# Why is my DIV height zero?

Tags: css, html

I have a div that is centered inside another div that contains my page content (in this case, a table with some information) However, I cant get it to show a background image because its height doesnt expand to the height of the table that it contains. Can someone tell me why?

```
<div>
    <div style="width: 900px; margin: auto; border: 1px solid #F00;">
        <table align="right">
            <tr><td>Something to make the hight of the container not zero</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED**

I apologise, I omitted the `align = "right"` on the table element (and have answered my question below)

Comment: Are you applying any styles to the table or div through a stylesheet?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s6A8W/  You likely have CSS that isn't shown here that's causing a problem.  Note in the example in the link, the height is, in fact, 20px, and that the border wraps your table just fine.

Comment: post your whole code or fiidle it. Actually it is working for me.

Comment: Time to break out the 'dev tools' in a browser, and try to work out what styles have been applied from unexpected sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

As soon as you put the attribute `align = "right"` on your table element, it turns it into a floating element (equivalent to the style property `float: right`. Floating elements are considered to take up no height, because they're floating... hence the height of the containing div remains zero.

Thanks for your inputs and my apologies once again for the omission.